# Tomcat Spring mvc - 404 error. Where is the mistake?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, model-view-controller

I have HTTP Status 404 on http://localhost:8080/hello-world

I am writing an application in Spring framework using MVC but it comes out with a 404 error
Please help me find the error

pom.xml source code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
  or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
  distributed with this work for additional information
  regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
  to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
  "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
  with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
  software distributed under the License is distributed on an
  "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
  KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
  specific language governing permissions and limitations
  under the License.
-->
<!-- $Id: pom.xml 642118 2008-03-28 08:04:16Z reinhard $ -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>web2</name>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>web2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.7</version>
        <configuration>
          <connectors>
            <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
              <port>8888</port>
              <maxIdleTime>30000</maxIdleTime>
            </connector>
          </connectors>
          <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${pom.artifactId}-${pom.version}</webAppSourceDirectory>
          <contextPath>/</contextPath>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.32</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--dependency>
      <groupId>org.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>[the artifact id of the block to be mounted]</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency-->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.17.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.17.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.17.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.17.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring5 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

web.xml source code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <display-name>spring-mvc-app1</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering/>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContextMVC.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

applicationContextMVC.xml source code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="web"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"/>
        <property name="enableSpringELCompiler" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="viewNames" value="*"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

HelloController.java source code

```
package web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("hello-world")
    public String sayHello(){
        return "hello_world";
    }


}
```

hello_world.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>My app</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>Hello world!</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: The first mistake is that you're using obsolete materials; use Spring Boot instead, and you can eliminate all of the config and the external Tomcat.

Comment: Which version of Tomcat are you using? Please add the errors you might find in the log files to your question.

Comment: I use apache tomcat 9 .

Comment: Your endpoint is `/hello-world` but it might be behind the context root `http://localhost:8080/<root>/hello-world` unless the latter is set to `/`.

Comment: Are you using standalone tomcat? in that case, you probably deploying it under the webapps folder. your project name is web2, so it will extract the war file as web2 folder under the webapps folder. I belive your context path will be in such case  HTTP://...../web2/hello-world